# Can I use JQuery to change the colour of a pattern created with CSS radial gradient?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using the following CSS to create a dotted background:

```
body {
 background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    green,
    green 20%,
    #000 0%, 
    #000
  );
  background-size: 10px 10px;
}
```

Can I change the colour of the dots in the pattern using JQuery? Codepen link: https://codepen.io/forTheLoveOfCode/pen/LOppaL?editors=1111

At the moment my JQuery is as follows (changes to linear gradient - something I managed to find):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#changeDots").on("click", function() {
       $("body").css({background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000))"});
  });
 });
```

Comment: Could you not add a class on click and have that class have the new colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radial gradients are hard to change in jQuery since there is an unlimited number of possibilities of rendering. Also, browser prefix can be a pain to manage.

Since `radial-gradient` is a value assigned to the `background-image`, you can use it in conjunction with `background-color`. So make your gradient from `transparent` to `black`, then you can easily change the `background-color` property :

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#changeDots").on("click", function() {
       $("body").css({backgroundColor: "red"});
  });
 });
```

```css
body {
 background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    transparent,
    transparent 20%,
    #000 0%, 
    #000
  );
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
      <br/>
      <button id = "changeDots" class = "btn btn-primary">
        Change the colour of green dots
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about just adding an extra class to body to add different behaviour. What do you think? Then you leave the styling inside the CSS file, and not in the JS part.

Comment: @Roy That would be what I'd do, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon it is very clever. If nothing else, I understand how radial gradient works better. Thanks.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon you have made my day, see the link to final project above. It would be much longer with an array of css classes.

Comment: @KatiaPunter Glad to hear it. Good luck for what's next!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write a `<style>` tag to the document head and, on click, write your CSS there, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('head').append('<style type="text/css" id="myStyle"/>');

 $("#changeDots").on("click", function() {
  var newStyle = 'body {' +
   'background: radial-gradient(' +
    'circle,' +
      'red,' +
      'red 20%,' +
      '#000 0%,' + 
      '#000' +
    ');' +
    'background-size: 10px 10px;' +
  '}';

  $('#myStyle').html(newStyle);
 });
});
```

(Obviously move your newStyle variable outside of the click event if it's not dynamic, you don't need to redeclare it over and over).

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwGNRd)

Answer (score 0):

[image: click here to see snap shot]
Just change 'body' to document.body in click event as shown in the above snap shot. I tried, it's workout:

`$(document).ready(function() {$("#changeDots").on("click", function() {
$(document.body).addClass("purpleDots");});});`

Thank you!!!

Comment: Sorry, already edited my codepen, done that. I want to iterate through an array of colours, though. I will try to use the udea of @Karl-AndréGagnon to do that